# I hope it's okay that I created a "fast-convolution" tag

Tags: feature-request

I think we needed it.  I searched the archive and attached that tag to a few questions that appeared to be about the topic.

Answer (score 2):

That's great!  The only additional thing I'd ask is that you create a one-sentence summary of the tag.

I get this at the top of the question list

[image]

when I [click on that as a tag on a question.](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fast-convolution)

Let me know if you don't see that and I'll see if I can add something.

Comment: just go ahead and write something.